# NSNumber Saving A Double

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data, osx-mountain-lion, nsnumber

Consider the three lines of code below

```
NSLog(@"start:%f", player.currentTime);
episode.resumeStamp = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:player.currentTime];
NSLog(@"end: %f", [episode.resumeStamp doubleValue]);
```

`episode` is a subclass of NSManagedObject, and player is an `AVAudioPlayer`. `player.currentTime` returns an `NSTimeInterval` (double). One would think when the code shown above runs, the "start:" and "end:" values will be the same. Oddly enough, the following is logged...

```
2012-09-30 20:13:02.941 MyApp[473:303] start:3.809116
2012-09-30 20:13:02.942 MyApp[473:303] end: 0.000000
2012-09-30 20:13:03.941 MyApp[473:303] start:4.809048
2012-09-30 20:13:03.942 MyApp[473:303] end: 0.000000
2012-09-30 20:13:04.941 MyApp[473:303] start:5.809116
2012-09-30 20:13:04.942 MyApp[473:303] end: 0.000000
```

Any ideas why this might be happening? Thank you so much for your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`episode` is most likely `nil`

Just add update the log to

```
NSLog(@"end: %f\nepisode %@", [episode.resumeStamp doubleValue], nil);
```

Comment: Wow I can't believe I missed that. Thank you for the fast response.